# Embedded RavenDB not initializing in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, ravendb

I'm having trouble with using the Embedded RavenDB inside of an MVC5 application. I've used the techniques described here, http://ravendb.net/kb/3/using-ravendb-in-an-asp-net-mvc-website to add a `DocumentStore` to the system, and initialize it.

At present my `Global.asax.cs` file looks like:

```
public static DocumentStore Store;

protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

    var store = new EmbeddableDocumentStore {Conventions = {IdentityPartsSeparator = "-"}, DataDirectory = "~\\App_Data\\Database"};
    store.Configuration.Port = 9090;
    store.UseEmbeddedHttpServer = true;
    //store.RunInMemory = true;

    Store = store;
    try
    {
        Store.Initialize();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex);
    }

    IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly(), Store);
}
```

Now, when I start the site, if I put a breakpoint on the `IndexCreation` line, or the `Debug.WriteLine` line they will *never* be hit. The code hits the `Store.Initialize();` call and never returns. If I pause the application, the debugger shows the application on the `Store.Initialize()` line.

There are no errors thrown and the `App_Data\Database` folder contains the makings of a RavenDB database. The only message from Raven says:

`System.ComponentModel.Composition Warning: 1 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'Raven.Database.Server.Security.OAuth.OAuthClientCredentialsTokenResponder' has been rejected. The composition remains unchanged.` having looked into it, I think that it's a red herring and can be ignored.

The last message I get in the Event Viewer is:

```
Raven (17148) 1-2HkcFe-F:\Projects\Websites\Test_App\App_Data\Database\Data: The database engine attached a database (1, F:\Projects\Websites\Test_App\App_Data\Database\Data). (Time=0 seconds)
```

Which looks like it's doing the right thing. It's just never returning from the `Initialize()` method, and so the site never loads. I've even tried running in x86 or x64 modes to no avail. I'm at a loss as to why this isn't loading.

If I uncomment out the `store.RunInMemory = true;` line, the site loads and the DB is there and works as expected, except that it obviously doesn't persist between sessions, and so isn't practical.

So, is there anything else I should look for?
Is there anything I've done wrong? (I'm purposely trying the simplest way I can to get the server to run, hence using the Global.asax)

Comment: Port 9090 is free? Tried another port? Could be a problem binding to it. Try something ridiculously high like 30000.

Comment: Hi, Port 9090 is fine, when running in Memory I can navigate to `http://localhost:9090/` and see the management page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've only managed to get this to work with the embedded version of RavenDB 3x, I'm unable to get 2.5x to work in any scenario, which means that I'm using the pre-release version, so having to pull from the ravendb nuget source:

`http://www.myget.org/F/ravendb3`

I presume once 3x is fully released, updating to that version will solve the problem as well.

**EDIT** - Now we can just use the nuget version as 3.x is released.